# Worklight Installation Directory

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ant, ibm-mobilefirst

In the tutorial of "Migrating an application from 
development to production", in preparing the ant file step, 
it asks me to go to the Worklight installation directory to get some Ant sample files and also uses this directory as a property in the Ant file itself.
The mentioned path is: "C:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\ 
configuration-samples", but I couldn't find it.
I downloaded worklight as plugin in eclipse Luna.
Is there a way to find the installation directory of worklight?

Answer (score 1):

You have a confusion between Worklight Studio and Worklight Server (production).

If you are moving to production, it is expected that you have the installation files for the Worklight Server(Production). 
The Eclipse plugin mentioned is the Worklight Studio (Development).
The installation files of Worklight Server (production) contains a setup that uses IBM Installation Manager to do an initial install of the server files in the mentioned path (i.e. This initial install will created the mentioned directory and its content like the configuration-samples dir).

So, before running the ant tasks you need to follow the steps in this page

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_running_ibm_installation_manager.html

More specifically the topic "Installing a new version of Worklight Server"

Also note that Worklight Studio (the eclipse plugin) is available for free, while the Worklight Server needs to be purchased from IBM.